# Is it possible to save and load a display configuration?

Tags: display

I have 2 displays for my computer, and a lot of times I need to change the configuration (from extended desktop to single desktop, changing wich one is the main screen, etc etc)

I wonder if there is a way to save and load these configurations for quick access in the future. I am aware of the existence of `xrandr` and I know it will probably be possible to write an alias for each setting, just wondering if there is an easier way or am I going to read the manual for it and do it that way.

Comment: There's a GUI front end to xrandr command called arandr, which allows saving the config as a script. You can load it back via the app itself or via command line

Comment: A simple click changes two displays from mirrored to extended in settings. There is no need to use `xrandr` for such a simple procedure. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install arandr

```
sudo apt install arandr
```

It is a graphical application where you can set all your screens in the way you want, apply the settings and afterwards you can save the settings (File -> Save As).

The best thing is that the settings are in fact saved as shell scripts with the  needed `xrandr` command that applies your configuration. Since they are plain text files you can open them in the favorite text editor to learn the syntax for `xrandr` or to modify them to your liking. In the end you can assign keyboard shortcuts to these shell scripts (either via `arandr` or via the general keyboard configuration tool), or you can add them to the menus for easy access.

For example, I have a script initially made with `arandr` that extends the screen to the right and later modified it manually to also change Broadcast-RGB to Full for some of the monitors I use where the Auto setting does not work properly.

The `arandr` script looks like this, so as you see it is a single `xrandr` command, so once you learn how to do it `arandr` will no longer be needed.

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full" --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-2 --off --output HDMI-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the commandline, you can use https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr for the same purpose.